# Convert a cross tab query from ms-access to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I use ms-Access to generate a query and I want to use it in MYSQL, but some ms-Access functions are not supported by MYSQL:

My ms-Access query that I want to convert to MYSQL is :

```
 TRANSFORM Count(s1.s1_ID) AS Comps1_ID
SELECT s1.s1_ID, s1.Name
FROM s1 INNER JOIN eq ON s1.s1_ID = eq.s1_ID
GROUP BY s1.s1_ID, s1.Name
PIVOT eq.Type;
```

There is my tables:

[image: tables]

There is data:

[image]

There is my output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately there is no pivot function for mysql, for unknown set of pivot elements you need to use dynamic sql, you may checkout `mysql dynamic pivot` question here is SO

Comment: Please can you help me to convert this query to mysql using dynamic sql?

Comment: Yes but I would need the table structures and some sample data.

Comment: ok I will edit my post and put a Screenshot

Comment: share your table data and what output you required then someone can help you to build query in mysql...you can prepare your data in #sqlfiddle also.

Comment: I added some Screenshots in my question

Comment: Ok added the answer check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way you need to do in mysql using dynamic sql

```
set @sql = null;
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'sum(case when eq.type = ''',
      eq.type,
      ''' then 1 else 0 end) AS ',
     concat('`',eq.type,'`')
    )
  ) into @sql
from eq ;

set @sql = concat('select s1.s1_id, s1.name, ', @sql, ' from s1 
                  join eq  on eq.s1_id = s1.s1_id
                  group by s1.s1_id
');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

**[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b82a1/1)**