# MS Access: joining 3 tables and unique rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have 2 tables:

**Table 1**

```
|ID |Total |Name |
|1  |100   |Car  |
|2  |200   |House|
|6  |600   |Car  |
```

and

**Table 2**

```
|ID |Total |Type |
|1  |200   |A    |
|1  |300   |B    |
|3  |100   |A    |
|3  |150   |B    |
|4  |400   |A    |
|5  |500   |B    |
|6  |700   |A    |
```

Basically I want to create a query to join all IDs to one result. I know there are 2 tables but one type of result needs joining 3 tables.

Result should be:

```
|ID|Total |Total A|Total B|Name |
|1 |100   |200    |300    |Car  | - IDs from all tables
|2 |200   |-      |-      |House| - ID from table1
|3 |-     |100    |150    |-    | - IDs from table2
|4 |-     |400    |-      |-    | - ID from table2(type A)
|5 |-     |-      |500    |-    | - ID from table2(type B)
|6 |600   |700    |-      |Dog  | - ID from table1 and table2(type A)
```

This is trivial example, there can be duplicate rows in table2 which needs group by. Also there are long where clause so performance is very low. All ID in result must be unique. This query executes when clicking button on form. Is it possible to create that kind of query? Maybe i should create some temp table before or something to simplify the query? Or maybe my table data structure is wrong?

**New additional data:**

**Table 1**

```
|ID |Total |Name |
|1  |100   |Car  |
|2  |200   |House|
|6  |600   |Car  |
|1  |400   |House|
```

In Table1 can be multiple same ID rows. Also column name specifies the column 'Total' sign(negative or positive). Lets say value 'Car' is negative and 'House' positive.

So the result should be:

```
|ID|Total |Total A|Total B|
|1 |300   |200    |300    
|2 |200   |-      |-         
|3 |-     |100    |150    
|4 |-     |400    |-          
|5 |-     |-      |500
|6 |-600  |700    |-
```

So we see that ID=1 Total=400-100 and ID=6 Total=-600 due to column name 'value'. My problem is that if i select Table1.Name to query then i get two same ID rows(ID=1) :S Is it possible to create such query so simple?

Comment: Yes, it's called a Cross tab query.  you're pivoting the data on type. Table structure seems normalized so I don't see a problem there.  [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222783/convert-a-cross-tab-query-from-ms-access-to-mysql)  What's nice about access is it can handle a dynamic number of columns, SQL Server can't do that without dynamic SQL!

Comment: This is not easy to do in MS Access with a single query because it supports neither `UNION ALL` in a subquery nor `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: UNION is necessary but duplicate IDs is not allowed..

Comment: I guess I"m missing something this seems like a straight forward cross tab query in MSAccess to me.  create query, switch to cross tab, join two tables on ID, add columns for ID, Total from table1, Name from table1, and then cross tab table2.Total on Table2.Type.  I don't have access on this system or I'd try it out.  seems simple...  No union no outer join.

Answer (score 1):

This reproduces your expected output based on your updated sample tables:

```
SELECT i.ID
 , First(T1.Total) AS [Total]
 , Sum(IIf(T2.Type='A',T2.Total,Null)) AS [Total A]
 , Sum(IIf(T2.Type='B',T2.Total,Null)) AS [Total B]

FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Table1
        UNION
       SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Table2) AS i 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, Sum(IIf(Table1.Name='House',Table1.Total,-Table1.Total)) AS Total 
             FROM Table1
             GROUP BY ID) AS T1 ON i.ID=T1.ID)
  LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON i.ID=T2.ID
GROUP BY i.ID
```

Comment: Thank you, its almost what i needed :) I re-edit my first question for additional information because in Table1 can be multiple same IDs and Total sign is related to another column value.

Comment: @wiz6: I updated my answer based on your new sample output.

Answer (score 0):

From an [example (Previous Stack Question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222783/convert-a-cross-tab-query-from-ms-access-to-mysql) I found perhaps this...

```
TRANSFORM max(t2Total) AS T2Total

SELECT B.ID, B.Total, B.Name
FROM (SELECT T1.ID, T1.Total, T1.Name, T2.Total as T2Total, T2.Type
      FROM table1 T1
      LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
      GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.Total, T1.Name
      UNION
      SELECT T1.ID, T1.Total, T1.Name, T2.Total, T2.Type
      FROM table1 T1
      RIGHT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
      GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.Total, T1.Name) B
PIVOT B.Type;
```

However it depends on what:  "there can be duplicate rows in table2 which needs group by" means... If you truly mean every value on the row is duplicated then you'd need to switch table2 in the above to:

`(Select distinct * from table2) T2`

Assuming you don't want the duplicates.

I am making an assumption that type and ID would be unique in table2.  If not then the "Max" may not give the desired result.

Comment: Pivot is intresting. This query doesnt give result which is only in Table2 and not in Table1 and only in Table1 and not in Table2. I think i need full outer join and union all but in access there is some workaround for that outer join..

Comment: Ah I get it now.  @GordonLinoff was right  Full outer can be simulated however using a left and right...

Comment: I'd need to see the third table and expected results, perhaps you just need to put `NULL as T3.Col1, NULL as T3.Col2,  NULL as T3.Col3` on one of the unions for the 3 columns you want for the third table.. or do you need to also pivot on that table?  in which case you may have to build a query on a query within access. and we'd have to know carnality of T3 to the other two tables and how the relate.

Comment: Sorry, there is no 3 tables. I meant that 3 tables is 3 joins(Table1, Table2(type=A), Table2(type=B).

Comment: that's what the pivot does for you.  you don't need to join more than once.  The system sees the Type field and says, oh you want a new column for each type listed. and then puts the max value of total for that given Id, type and name in the column.

Comment: There are syntax error in TRANSFORM statement. Cant fix it :S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113676/discussion-between-wiz6-and-xqbert).

Comment: Sadly I can't I recommend just building a query that has the union that does the left and right joins.  then building a query on that one that transforms the data.